# Drag/Drop - Jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

what is the correct string for apply an event "drop" in all html tag that contain for example the attribute "[data-type]"??
I use library: http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag#demos

```
$("[data-type]").drop("start",function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("data-type"));
});
```

In this case, when i drag an element on all elements that have attribute "data-type", should be print his value of "data-type" attribute but not work.
This event has been written after "dragend" event but also after "drag" event, the result it's the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$("[data-type]").drop(function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).attr("data-type"));
});
```

Or try to log the object from the drop function to inspect what properties are existent.